# How to draw a battery connecting 3D surfaces?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw two circular surfaces connected by a battery at a certain distance. The problem is that I'm having a really hard time trying to combine 3D plots with 2D lines. Here's the code I've written:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc, backgrounds, patterns, circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}
\def\R{1}
\def\hc{4}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{60}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, rotate=-90,
                    transform shape, circuit ee IEC]

    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=-\hc/2]
        \draw (0,0) arc(\tdplotmainphi+180:\tdplotmainphi-180:\R);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=\hc/2]
        \draw (0,0) arc(\tdplotmainphi+180:\tdplotmainphi-180:\R);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=-\R]
        \draw (0, \hc/2) to [battery={info={$V_0$}}] (0, -\hc/2) {};
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=2*\R]
        \draw [|-|] (0, \hc/2) node[below] {$d(t)$} -- (0, -\hc/2);
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

That leads to this abomination:

[image]

I don't understand why the lines are plotted in those places, and why the annotation of the distance appears so weird. I suppose it has something to do with the rotation of the 3D axes, but I don't know how to fix this in order to show two-dimensional lines. Also the label appears inverted... although that is not such a big problem (I just haven't figured out how to solve it yet). The main issue is the fact that the lines are so weird.

How can this drawing be made correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very often symbolic coordinates help tremendously when accessing coordinates in something that you have already drawn. In addition, I think it is cleaner (though not absolutely necessary) to use `tdplot_screen_coords` for the 2d parts.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{60}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, rotate=-90,
                    transform shape, circuit ee IEC,
                    declare function={R=1;hc=4;}]
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=-hc/2]
        \draw circle[radius=R];
        \path (\tdplotmainphi+180:R) coordinate (tl)
        (\tdplotmainphi:R) coordinate (bl);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=hc/2]
        \draw circle[radius=R];
        \path (\tdplotmainphi+180:R) coordinate (tr)
        (\tdplotmainphi:R) coordinate (br);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords]
     \draw (tl) to [battery={info={$V_0$}}] (tr);
     \draw[|-|] (bl) -- (br);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to move the line that marks the distance a little bit lower? I'd like it not to touch the surfaces, but I don't know how to move it becuase the coordinates that define it don't specify anything about it's vertical position.

Answer (score 0):

Something when an user not have a minimal working example, as alternative, I suggest to use a tool, called  [`Mathcha`](https://www.mathcha.io/editor) on line that export in `TikZ`. Obviously it's not a good approach at all but sometimes, if some users like to draw, you can get some good results. Try to believe :-)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document} 
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Shape: Ellipse [id:dp14965629917587342] 
\draw   (152.36,86.31) .. controls (174.91,86.37) and (192.73,118.41) .. (192.14,157.88) .. controls (191.55,197.35) and (172.79,229.3) .. (150.24,229.24) .. controls (127.68,229.18) and (109.87,197.14) .. (110.45,157.67) .. controls (111.04,118.2) and (129.8,86.25) .. (152.36,86.31) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Ellipse [id:dp6565453485959398] 
\draw   (400.64,87.69) .. controls (423.2,87.75) and (441.01,119.79) .. (440.43,159.25) .. controls (439.84,198.72) and (421.08,230.67) .. (398.52,230.61) .. controls (375.97,230.55) and (358.15,198.51) .. (358.74,159.04) .. controls (359.33,119.58) and (378.09,87.63) .. (400.64,87.69) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da09296239339147117] 
\draw    (152.36,86.31) -- (236.5,87) ;
%Shape: Battery [id:dp027393344698937616] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (316.5,87.2) -- (280.5,87.11) (272.43,117.09) -- (272.57,57.09) (272.5,87.09) -- (236.5,87) (283.66,102.12) -- (280.46,102.11) -- (280.54,72.11) -- (283.74,72.12) -- (283.66,102.12) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da5155708033133359] 
\draw    (316.5,87) -- (400.64,87.69) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da2329334269181791] 
\draw    (150.24,229.24) -- (398.52,230.61) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da4881709177101803] 
\draw    (150.74,219.24) -- (150.24,236.24) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da9330360338163168] 
\draw    (397.74,220.24) -- (397.24,237.24) ;

% Text Node
\draw (265,30.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large]  {$V_{0}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here you can find the screenshot of the output:

[image]